# How to disable transaction in Django Admin?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, transactions, django-admin

I used **`@transaction.non_atomic_requests`** for **the overridden `save()`** in **`Person` model** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    
    @transaction.non_atomic_requests # Here
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And, I also used **`@transaction.non_atomic_requests`** for **the overridden `save_model()`** in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.db import transaction

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @transaction.non_atomic_requests # Here
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
```

But, when adding data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is used as shown below. *I use **PostgreSQL** and these logs below are **the queries of PostgreSQL** and you can check [**On PostgreSQL, how to log queries with transaction queries such as "BEGIN" and "COMMIT"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601):

[image]

And, when changing data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is used as shown below:

[image]

And, when clicking **`Delete` button** of **Change person** as shown below:

[image]

Then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is used as shown below:

[image]

And, when selecting **`Delete selected persons`** and clicking **`Go` button** of **Select person to change** as shown below:

[image]

Then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is used as shown below:

[image]

So, how can I disable **transaction** in **Django Admin**?

Answer (score 0):

First to disable **transaction** when adding and changing data, you need to override [**changeform_view()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1743) in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @csrf_protect_m # Here
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

Because by default, [**changeform_view()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1743) has **`with transaction.atomic(...):`** to use **transaction** when adding and changing data as shown below:

```py
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    
    # ...
    
    @csrf_protect_m
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)): # Here
            return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```

As a result, when adding data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is not used as shown below:

[image]

And, when changing data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is not used as shown below:

[image]

Next to disable **transaction** when clicking **`Delete` button** of **Change person** then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data, you need to override [**delete_view()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L2102) in **`Person` admin** as shown below:

```py
# "store/admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

csrf_protect_m = method_decorator(csrf_protect)

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    @csrf_protect_m # Here
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        return self._delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

Because by default, [**delete_view()**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L2102) has **`with transaction.atomic(...):`** to use **transaction** when clicking **`Delete` button** of **Change person** then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data as shown below:

```py
class ModelAdmin(BaseModelAdmin):
    
    # ...
    
    @csrf_protect_m
    def delete_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        with transaction.atomic(using=router.db_for_write(self.model)): # Here
            return super()._delete_view(request, object_id, extra_context)
```

As a result, when clicking **`Delete` button** of **Change person** as shown below:

[image]

Then clicking **`Yes, I'm sure` button** to delete data as shown below:

[image]

**Transaction** is not used as shown below:

[image]

Lastly, you don't need to disable **transaction** for **`Delete selected persons`** because by default **transaction** is not used for **Django Admin Actions** including **`Delete selected persons`**. *You can see [**my post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74965894/by-default-is-transaction-used-in-django-admin-actions) explaining more about **Django Admin Actions with non-transaction by default**.